# Split a filename into absolute paths in Scala

Tags: scala, path, split

Given the string

```
val path = "/what/an/awesome/path"
```

how can I use Scala to create a list of absolute paths for each directory in path? 
The result should be:

```
List(/what, /what/an, /what/an/awesome, /what/an/awesome/path)
```

Bonus points for an elegant, functional solution.

Comment: I'm truly astonished by all the high quality answers. I wish I could accept more than one answer but since this isn't possible, I will accept the first correct one. Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
val path = "/what/an/awesome/path"
val file = new java.io.File(path)
val prefixes = Iterator.iterate(file)(_.getParentFile).takeWhile(_ != null).toList.reverse
```

Comment: I have never seen this method before. Could you please tell me if I understood correctly? After every iteration the object returned by `.getParentFile` becomes the "new" `file`?

Comment: Nice. +1. This yields the root directory as the first element though?

Comment: @huynhjl Appending a `.drop(1)` fixes that easily enough :-)

Comment: @Tempus yes, it is ``Iterator.iterate(startingValue)(functionToDeriveNext)`` .  There are a number of similar factory methods on the companions for various collection types.  ``Iterator.continually`` is interesting too, for example.  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/Iterator$.html

Comment: Note that if the path is not already from the root of the filesystem, you might want to `.getCanonicalPath` on it.

Answer (score 8):

```
val path = "/what/an/awesome/path"

scala> path.tail.split("/").scanLeft(""){_ + "/" + _}.tail.toList
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(/what, /what/an, /what/an/awesome, /what/an/awesome/path)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Jesse Eichar's new [Scala IO library](http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io-doc/0.2.0/index.html#!/overview) (version 0.2.0) it looks like you can do something like this:

```
val path  = Path("/what/an/awesome/path")
val paths = (path :: path.parents).reverse
```

You might want to convert the Path objects in the resulting list to Strings but perhaps they would be safer and more useful left as Path objects.

This library, as far as I know, is being considered for inclusion in the Scala distribution.

Answer (score 2):

```
path.drop(1).split("/").foldLeft(List.empty[String])((list, string) => ((list.headOption.getOrElse("") + "/" + string) :: list)).reverse.toList
```

There's probably a cleaner way using scanLeft, but I wasn't able to figure it out

Comment: Probably around those lines `path.split("/").drop(1).scanLeft("")((s,elem) => s + "/" + elem).drop(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Fancy-pants regex method:

```
val R = "(/.*)/".r
(path + '/').inits.collect{case R(x) => x}.toList
```